# How can I apply multiple conditions in Pandas, with Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How can I apply multiple conditions in pandas?
For example I have this dataframe

```
Country   VAT        
RO       RO1449488
RO       RO1449489
RO       RO1449486
MD       2980409450027
```

For example I want for the Countries with RO, to delete the "RO" from VAT and remain just number.
Or for example if the Country is not RO and let(VAT) is 13, to add "03" in front of VAT

Output to be like

```
Country   VAT        
RO       1449488
RO       1449489
RO       1449486
MD       032980409450027
```

I know how to do this with openpyxl, but pandas is new for me and I find pandas syntax to be harder to understand.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to have something else than @mozway one-liner, you can use `apply()` to make any modification over your DataFrame. Defining your code in a function :

```
def myFunc(x):
    if x['VAT'].startswith("RO"):
        result = x['VAT'][2:]
    elif x['Country'] != 'RO' and len(x['VAT']) == 13:
        result = "03" + x['VAT']
    # add other conditions here

    return result
```

Then you can apply it to your DataFrame row by row with `axis=1`

```
df['VAT'] = df.apply(myFunc, axis=1)
```

```
# Output
  Country              VAT
0      RO          1449488
1      RO          1449489
2      RO          1449486
3      MD  032980409450027
```

Comment: `apply` is equivalent to a loop, it will be slow on large datasets

Comment: I know that `apply` is closer to a loop than your solution, but isn't this still better to use a function from `pandas` library than a plain custom loop iterating without using `iterrow()` or `iteritems()` ?

Comment: In terms of performance, likely not (in terms of clarity, yes)

Comment: Note that I did not downvote your answer, it is still perfectly valid if performance is not required

Answer (score 3):

You can use boolean selection with [`numpy.select`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html):

```
import numpy as np
                       # condition1            condition2
df['VAT'] = np.select([df['Country'].eq('RO'), df['VAT'].str.len().eq(13)],
                       # replacement1      
                      [df['VAT'].str.replace('^RO', '', regex=True),
                      '03'+df['VAT']], # replacement2
                       df['VAT']       # default
                     )
```

output:

```
  Country              VAT
0      RO          1449488
1      RO          1449489
2      RO          1449486
3      MD  032980409450027
```